# Need to Update XML Tag value at run time

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

In the code below I'm trying to update one of the tag value. My problem is that which tag value I need to update, I know only at run time. 
Below code does not work to update the tag value even though I'm able to get the tag value by this code.

```
def temp1="""
<TradeRecord>
   <TradeId>1000</TradeId> 
   <SecurityId>10382456</SecurityId> 
   <TradeType>SELLL</TradeType> 
   <TradeDate>2014-03-21</TradeDate> 
   <Broker>100</Broker> 
   <Exchange>1</Exchange> 
   <Status>INIT</Status> 
   <Quantity>12765</Quantity> 
   <ApprovedBy /> 
</TradeRecord>
"""

def records = new XmlParser().parseText(temp1)

childRecords = records.children()
j = childRecords.size()
def tagname = 'Quantity'
for (int i=0; i<j; i++){
   if (childRecords[i].name() == tagname) {
      log.info childRecords[i].text()
      childRecords[i].text() = "9999"
      log.info childRecords[i].text()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign to the `text()`-getter, but there is the `value`, which has a setter; e.g.:

```
childRecords[i].value = "9999"
```

But this also can be done more groovy:

```
    def temp1="""
    <TradeRecord>
       <TradeId>1000</TradeId> 
       <SecurityId>10382456</SecurityId> 
       <TradeType>SELLL</TradeType> 
       <TradeDate>2014-03-21</TradeDate> 
       <Broker>100</Broker> 
       <Exchange>1</Exchange> 
       <Status>INIT</Status> 
       <Quantity>12765</Quantity> 
       <ApprovedBy /> 
    </TradeRecord>
    """

    def records = new XmlParser().parseText(temp1)
    final tagname = 'Quantity'

    records."$tagname".each{
            it.value = '9999'
    }

    println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(records)
```